# Django AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've got the following models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf import settings

    class User(AbstractUser):

        username = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
        email    = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

        USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

        def __str__(self):
            return "{}".format(self.email)


    class UserProfile(models.Model):

        user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                    related_name='profile')

        dob = models.DateField()
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        receive_newsletter = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
```

So I have overwritten the default `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py` to be:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'
```

but I'm getting the following error when running migrations:

> "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" %
>   settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
>   AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'kofiapi.User' that has not been
>   installed

My project's structure is as follows:

- myapp

  - api

    - users

      - __init__.py
      - models.py
- myproject

  - settings.py

I have tried the following variations yet all failed:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.api.users.User'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.users.User'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.api.User'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'
```

Any indication of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you migrate the new model?

Comment: In my case there was a `from django.contrib.auth import forms` in one of my files(in `models.py`) from which `get_user_model()` was being called. The problem was solved by removing these imports.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE.** try this: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'` and `myapp.api.users` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Nope, it's there under `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: And do you already have `__init__.py` at the same level, where your user model located?

Comment: `AUTH_USER_MODEL` should be in `app_label.YourUserModel` format, so `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.User'` in your case. If you already registered application in installed apps as `myapp.api`, everything should work.

Comment: I had only registered `myapp` did not registered `myapp.api` but I just did it and still getting the same error :(

Comment: To be sure. `myapp > api > users > models.py` or `myapp > api > models.py` ?

Comment: First one `myapp > api > users > models.py`. I've got multiple subfolders, one for products, one for orders, one for users, etc, all under api

Comment: try this: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'` and `myapp.api.users` in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: this seems to have worked, A.Takhirov, please update your main answers with the comments in here so I can mark it as correct. Thanks